Spawner Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
when I run one of my launch files that calls this launch file I got this error:
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1715563423.016316240] [controller_spawner]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1715563424.992640859] [controller_spawner]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1715563425.022922823] [controller_spawner]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 18581, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=controller_spawner --params-file /root/ROS2Activities/workspace/challenge3_ws/install/puzzlebot_control/share/puzzlebot_control/config/puzzlebot_joint_states.yaml'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 18583, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner base_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=controller_spawner --params-file /root/ROS2Activities/workspace/challenge3_ws/install/puzzlebot_control/share/puzzlebot_control/config/puzzlebot_diff_control.yaml'].

This is my launch file where I put the spawner node:
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch_ros.actions import Node, LoadComposableNodes
from launch_ros.descriptions import ComposableNode
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

def generate_launch_description():
    # Definir los argumentos de lanzamiento
    declare_robot_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'robot', default_value='puzzlebot',
        description='Name of the robot')

    # config = os.path.join(
    #   get_package_share_directory('puzzlebot_control'),
    #   'config',
    #   'puzzlebot_joint_states.yaml'
    #   )
    # config2 = os.path.join(
    #   get_package_share_directory('puzzlebot_control'),
    #   'config',
    #   'puzzlebot_diff_control.yaml'
    #   )

    controller_manager_node = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        output='screen'
    )

    # Spawn controller manager
    controller_spawner_joint_state = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        name='controller_spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_controller', '--controller-manager', "/controller_manager"],
        output='screen',
        parameters=[
                PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('puzzlebot_control'), 'config', 'puzzlebot_joint_states.yaml'])
                ]
    )

    controller_spawner_base_control = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        name='controller_spawner',
        arguments=["base_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
        output='screen',
        parameters=[
                PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('puzzlebot_control'), 'config', 'puzzlebot_diff_control.yaml']),
                ]
    )

    # Puzzlebot wheel velocity node
    wheel_vel_node = Node(
        package='puzzlebot_control',
        executable='wheel_Vel',
        name='wheel_vel'
    )

    # Return the launch description
    return LaunchDescription([
        # declare_robot_arg,
        controller_manager_node,
        controller_spawner_joint_state,
        controller_spawner_base_control,
        wheel_vel_node
    ])

When I run ros2 service list I see the controller_manager services.
If I try to run a demo I got this:
root@39c6352512cd:~/ROS2Activities/workspace/challenge3_ws# ros2 launch gazebo_ros2_control_demos cart_example_position.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-05-13-22-16-53-603921-39c6352512cd-22982
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [22983]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [22985]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [22987]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [22989]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715638614.022779669] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cart
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715638614.022856259] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slideBar
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715638614.022861125] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1715638614.131374087] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1715638614.131624020] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1715638614.132626040] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1715638614.143451239] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1715638614.143659700] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1715638644.201204370] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1715638644.202224074] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 22989, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -topic robot_description -entity cart --ros-args'].
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process started with pid [23392]
[ros2-5] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-5]: process has died [pid 23392, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_state_broadcaster'].
[INFO] [ros2-6]: process started with pid [23488]
[ros2-6] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-6]: process has died [pid 23488, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_trajectory_controller'].
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715638716.620805412] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715638716.621410081] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 22985, exit code -2, cmd 'gzclient'].
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 22987]
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gzserver-1]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715638721.635109716] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=15)
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '10.0' seconds after receiving 'SIGTERM', escalating to 'SIGKILL'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGKILL' to process[gzserver-1]
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 22983, exit code -9, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].


Can you launch the demos from gazebo_ros2_control_demos successfully?
If yes, please post the complete console output. Something  went wrong before the spawner reports that it can't find the service.

I tried to run one of the demos but I got an error, I put it in the main question

Here is the link to the project, the launch file I am running is Puzzlebot_gazebo but it calls others launch file, the launch file with the controller is in puzzlebot_control https://github.com/Antonioleon13/ROS2Activities/tree/main/workspace/challenge3_ws/src

If the demos did not launch then there is no need to have a look at your project.
But there is no need to launch a ros2_control_node if you use gazebo_ros2_control, which starts an instance of controller_manager by itself. See example_9 or any of the gazebo_ros2_control_demos how to do this.
But first you have to get the demos running.
Have you installed gazebo_ros2_control correctly? There is not a single output from it in your last console log (please include the command which you have started).

Run rosdep
see what ros2 pkg xml gazebo_ros2_control -t version gives you

